# Windows 11 doesnt see docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

my first post
Im trying check docker-compose version in cmd, but it doesnt work.
I get: docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
If im trying check docker, all working fine
Path in env variables is correctly.

I was trying reboot pc, reload Docker desktop, but all my attemps faild(

Im expecting, that cmd will see my docker-compose)

Comment: What version of docker are you using? If you have the latest, docker-compose is deprecated. It's been migrated to `docker compose` no `-`.  Source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/migrate/ --- `From July 2023 Compose V1 stopped receiving updates. It’s also no longer available in new releases of Docker Desktop.`

Comment: Im using 24.0.6
but when im trying create build without " - ", Im getting same message:
PS C:\Users\boof4\IdeaProjects\p_ss_bank_34> docker compose build
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'

Comment: I should have been more clear. What version of Docker desktop are you using? Open Docker Desktop, go to settings and check the version. Also there should be a check box to use docker compose V2, make sure the box is checked and restart docker.

Comment: Try this too: `"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe" compose --help` see if this works

Comment: You can find if there are multiple `docker` commands if you ran `where docker`. Also make sure your docker desktop is running in the background before trying any docker commands.

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe" compose --help. This give me faq only about Docker commands :(
I can use docker, but the problem, that I cant use docker compose commands

Comment: docker desktop ver 4.25.1 and docker ver 24.0.6

Comment: If this command `"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe" compose --help` is giving you the help options, then that means docker compose is installed. There's something wrong with your environment path.

Give us both the output of `where docker` command from cmd and copy and paste your current environment path here.

Comment: way to Docker:  C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe

Comment: env PATH: C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin

Comment: That can't possible be the only thing in your env path. If it's already there, then my guess is that you have docker.exe somewhere else. Anyways, you should be able to run `"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe" compose up`.

Comment: C:\Users\boof4>"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe" compose up
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'

Comment: :(   So, I think, maybe i have some conflict with my windows 11(

Comment: Yeah that's really odd. Have you tried reinstalling?

Comment: Yes, I tried few times)) 
thanks for your help, I will try resolve this problem in future

Comment: I decide this problem by your answer. Only if i write full path without the quotes  - it work)

Comment: D:\Applications\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-compose.exe -up -d